# socat localhost proxy with 'Connection refused'

Tags: proxy, netcat, socat

I want to play with socat to setup a localhost proxy , which could redirect my request from local proxy I setup to a remote server.
Below are 2 commands I try (by google)

##### Command 1: works right on localhost

###### start socat server

```
socat -d  TCP6-LISTEN:8080,fork,reuseaddr TCP4:drsol.com:80
```

###### client connect socat server

```
curl -I -6 http://localhost:8080/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 25 Dec 2022 13:06:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Tue, 10 Jun 2014 17:35:11 GMT
ETag: "2482ce4-2-4fb7ebff1050b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 2
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

##### Command 2: 'Connection refused' error on localhost server terminal

###### setup socat server

```
socat TCP6-LISTEN:8000 PROXY:localhost:drsol.com:80,proxyport=8080
```

###### connect socat server

```
curl -v http://localhost:8000/ 
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x55fce853a968; line 1789 (connection #-5000)
* Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == 'localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1'
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
* family0 == v4, family1 == v6
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* STATE: CONNECT => CONNECTING handle 0x55fce853a968; line 1850 (connection #0)
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
* STATE: CONNECTING => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x55fce853a968; line 1982 (connection #0)
* STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x55fce853a968; line 2003 (connection #0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.80.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* STATE: DO => DID handle 0x55fce853a968; line 2099 (connection #0)
* STATE: DID => PERFORMING handle 0x55fce853a968; line 2218 (connection #0)
* STATE: PERFORMING => DONE handle 0x55fce853a968; line 2417 (connection #0)
* multi_done
* Empty reply from server
* The cache now contains 0 members
* Closing connection 0
* Expire cleared (transfer 0x55fce853a968)
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

###### on the socat server terminal "Connection refused"

```
2022/12/25 21:10:42 socat[46697] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:8080, 16): Connection refused
```

My question is : what was the difference between command 1 and command 2 , and why the connection refused happend on command 2?
(I am new to socat and on my way of learning it)

Comment: PROXY:localhost:drsol.com:80,proxyport=8080  instructs Socat to connect to localhost port 8080 (using TCP4), and send a HTTP CONNECT request to this server, requesting proxied connection to drsol.com:80